# Terminal de Python - En la plataforma Anaconda - Spyder (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, consola

buenos días a todos los usuari@s. Disculpen si la pregunta es 'inoportuna' pero son mis primeros pasos con python.
Tengo un problema de visualización en la consola. Estoy trabajando con Anaconda Navigator. Spyder (Python 3.7). Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto ciertas sentencias no se muestra el resultado completo en la consola. Es algún problema de tamaño del buffer que no consigo encontrar la opción de configuración.
Ejemplo: Ejecuto la sentencia ''describe()'' sobre un dataset y aunque se indica que el resultado son 7 columnas solo se muestran 4; indicando que faltan datos con los símbolos: ''...''

¿Cómo puedo cambiar la configuración para visualizar todo el resultado?
Gracias a tod@s[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Olvidaste mencionar que trabajas con `pandas`, lo cual es relevante porque es precisamente pandas quien está limitando el tamaño de la salida, y no la consola o Spyder.

Ya que un dataframe puede ser muy grande, por defecto pandas elige siempre mostrarte un subconjunto del mismo. Puedes configurar cuántas filas, columnas, etc quieres que te muestre, mediante por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

La última opción es para ampliar el ancho de cada línea que pandas pueda volcar. Si le pides volcar varias columnas y no le caben en esa "línea", las romperá, mostrando primero N columnas que quepan, luego otras N, etc. Si tu terminal permite desplazamiento horizontal puede resultar más legible ponerle una longitud enorme como 1000 para que le entre todo sin necesidad de partirlo, y luego ya lo miras tú haciendo scroll.

Tienes más opciones [en la documentacion](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options)

Comment: !Genial! Muchas gracias :)